# Avoid pointer arithmetic, fix clang tidy error

Tags: c++, c++11, clang-tidy

Is it possible to solve the following issue clang tidy is throwing out.
`error: do not use pointer arithmetic [cppcoreguidelines-pro-bounds-pointer-arithmetic,-warnings-as-errors]`

The project I am using is a mix of C/C++ and no changes can be made on the C side.

```
extern const Test_Ptr* test;
auto enable = (Test_Ptr->pIndex[1].base == 1)
                        ? true
                        : false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the pointer in a span and access through that:

```
// these should be defined somewhere in the C library in some form
constexpr std::size_t pIndexLength = 2;  // or whatever is the actual length
using T = decltype(*test);               // or whatever the pointed type is

span<T> pIndex {Test_Ptr->pIndex, pIndexLength};
int base = pIndex[1].base;
```

There is no standard implementation of `span` until C++20, so in older language version you need to use a non-standard implementation.

Another approach is to not use that convention validation option.

Comment: This just makes the code so much harder to follow and maintain. That sounds like a rather silly clang-tidy error to be honest.

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 That's also a valid approach.

Answer (score 0):

That warning (promoted to error by your configuration) is, frankly, silly.

You could work around it but only by making your code *harder* to follow and maintain.

Just turn off `cppcoreguidelines-pro-bounds-pointer-arithmetic`.